# Could not find method bootJar() for arguments

Tags: spring-boot

While building the gradle project I am getting below error-
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/vdubey/Documents/microservices/workspace/Promo-Service/build.gradle' line: 30
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Promo-Service'.

  > Could not find method bootJar() for arguments [build_3jq74tz48uic808y18txabjvx$_run_closure1@5c4aa147] on root project 'Promo-Service' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Any clue why it is failing?

Comment: post the part of your gradle file around line 30, and which gradle command you try running.

Comment: I am using bootJar {
    baseName = 'promo-service'
    version =  '0.0.1'
} trying to convert my gradle into jar .I remove this and had put into other location but still didn't work ?

Comment: Did you manage to figure out the problem? I am following the spring boot Docker guide and have encountered the same error

Answer (score 7):

I had this error while following the [Spring Boot with Docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) guide because my application is using Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE and [bootRun](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/api/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/run/BootRun.html) was only introduced in 2.0.0.

Luckily, the Spring Boot Docker guide code is in a Github repository, so I was able to navigate back to a pre 2.0.0 version: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot-docker/tree/8933f6efa9a94cf596095658dc0b81986d11a3ec

See the completed [build.gradle](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot-docker/blob/8933f6efa9a94cf596095658dc0b81986d11a3ec/complete/build.gradle) file for 1.5.10-RELEASE:

```
// This is used as the docker image prefix (org)
group = 'springio'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot-docker'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

// tag::task[]
docker {
    name "${project.group}/${jar.baseName}"
    files jar.archivePath
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "${jar.archiveName}"])
}
// end::task[]
```

Answer (score 6):

Consider checking the presence of gradle plugin for Spring Boot:
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot

For Gradle 2.1 and later:

```
plugins {
  id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.1.0.RELEASE"
}
```

For older Gradle versions:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE"
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I am following [official Spring testing-web guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/). They offer initial gradle file as below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
}

plugins { id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.4.RELEASE" }

ext { springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE' }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-testing-web'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.6'
}
```

But when I run the `./gradlew clean` command I get the below exception

```
Could not find method bootJar() for arguments [] on root project '' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

The problem is instead of using `plugins { id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.4.RELEASE" }` use `id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.1.3.RELEASE"`. Also don't forget the java and io.spring.dependency-management plugins.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
```

> **8.1. Reacting to the Java plugin**
>
> When Gradle’s java plugin is applied to a project, the Spring Boot plugin:
>   Creates a BootJar task named bootJar that will create an executable,
>   fat jar for the project. The jar will contain everything on the
>   runtime classpath of the main source set; classes are packaged in
>   BOOT-INF/classes and jars are packaged in BOOT-INF/lib
>
> **8.4. Reacting to the dependency management plugin**
>
> When the io.spring.dependency-management plugin is applied to a
>   project, the Spring Boot plugin will automatically import the
>   spring-boot-dependencies bom.

I shared valid build.gradle file below which can be a starting point for anyone who have this problem.

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.1.3.RELEASE"
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.1.3.RELEASE'
}
// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    mavenCentral()
}

bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.softwarelabs.App'
    baseName = 'spring-boot-integration-test'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    // This dependency is found on compile classpath of this component and consumers.
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    // Use JUnit test framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.6'
}
```

For more details please check the [spring boot gradle plugin documentation getting started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#getting-started) part.

Check how the [Spring Boot plugin reacts by other plugins](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#reacting-to-other-plugins).

Answer (score 0):

I had this error while building a repository I had downloaded.
I was able to resolve the same by modifying my `build.gradle` to include a buildscript dependency for `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` and apply `org.springframework.boot` as a plugin

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '<Spring boot version>'
}
repositories {
     ...<my repository config>... 

 }
// These are gradle build dependencies and not application requirements
dependencies {
    ...<other dependencies>...
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
}
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```